# Rails CKEditor Gem giving 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ckeditor

I am using this CKEditor gem: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

I have followed the instructions on the README, but when I try to place a `f.cktext_area` I get some 404s:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/ckeditor/config.js?t=DAED 404 (Not Found) ckeditor.js?body=1:78
GET http://localhost:5000/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css?t=DAED 404 (Not Found) ckeditor.js?body=1:78
GET http://localhost:5000/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=DAED 404 (Not Found) ckeditor.js?body=1:78
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined ckeditor.js?body=1:214
```

I have run `rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip` and `rake db:migrate`

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)` is in `application.rb` 
`mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'` is in `routes.rb`
and `//= require ckeditor/init` is in my JS...

I have also restarted my development server, but am still getting these 404s.

In my `rake routes`:

```
ckeditor        /ckeditor                       Ckeditor::Engine

Routes for Ckeditor::Engine:
        pictures GET    /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#index
                 POST   /pictures(.:format)             ckeditor/pictures#create
         picture DELETE /pictures/:id(.:format)         ckeditor/pictures#destroy
attachment_files GET    /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#index
                 POST   /attachment_files(.:format)     ckeditor/attachment_files#create
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I should add that `localhost:5000/assets/ckeditor/config.js` does work as do the rest prepended with `/assets/`... why won't `ckeditor.js` use the correct asset path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember where I found the solution (someone on a Github issues thread).

This worked for me:

Add this `/lib/tasks/ckeditor.rake`:

```
require 'fileutils'

desc "Create nondigest versions of all ckeditor digest assets"
task "assets:precompile" => :environment do
  fingerprint = /\-([0-9a-f]{32})\./
  for file in Dir["public/assets/ckeditor/**/*"]
    # Skip file unless it has a fingerprint
    next unless file =~ fingerprint

    # Get filename of this file without the digest
    # (example) public/assets/ckeditor/config.js
    nondigest = file.sub fingerprint, '.'

    # Create a filename relative to public/assets
    # (example) public/assets/ckeditor/config.js => ckeditor/config.js
    filename = nondigest.sub 'public/assets/', ''
    filename = filename.sub /.gz$/, ''          # Remove .gz for correct asset checking

    # Fetch the latest digest for this file from assets
    latest_digest = Rails.application.assets.find_asset(filename).try(:digest)

    # Debug information
    puts '---- ' + file + ' ----'

    # Compare digest of this file to latest digest
    # [1] is the enclosed capture in the fingerprint regex above
    this_digest = file.match(fingerprint)[1]
    if (this_digest == latest_digest)
      # This file's digest matches latest digest, copy
      puts 'Matching digest, copying ' + file
      FileUtils.cp file, nondigest, verbose: true
    else
      # This file's digest doesn't match latest digest, ignore
      puts 'Latest digest: ' + latest_digest
      puts 'This digest:   ' + this_digest
      puts 'Non-matching digest, not copying ' + file
    end

    # Debug information
    puts '---- end ----'
  end
end
```

Comment: i have added this task, do i have to run this task seperately?

Comment: @error-404no you don't have to. this task is automatically executed when you hit `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` (or `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this on your **config/application.rb**

```ruby
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
  end
```

Founded here https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/468